# Why does 'onhashchange'in(window) work?

Tags: javascript

```
'onhashchange'in(window)
```

Having `in()` work is not a surprise, as `new(XMLHTTPRequest)` or `typeof(x)` are other examples of this construct, but not having to separate the string and `in` is.

Is this per ECMAScript specs? It works in Chrome and FF, haven't tested IE.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, can I clarify it some more please.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, there's no difference whether you wrap `window` in parenthesis or not in this particular instance. Either way, it checks for this member on the `window` object.

Might be less confusing if you use spaces:

```
'onhashchange' in (window)
```

The same as

```
'onhashchange' in window
```

`in` is not a function, but when you remove the spaces I can see how you read it as such. One advantage to wrapping `window` in parenthesis is that you can then minify the code:

```
'onhashchange'in(window)
```

Something you could not do without the parenthesis.

Comment: It's the same thing with `typeof "foo"` V.S. `typeof ("foo")` `typeof` and `in` are operators and don't need parenthesis

Comment: @gdoron I'm thinking the parens are there for the same reason semicolons should be used - in case the code is minified or compressed.

Comment: `The typeof operator is used in either of the following ways:

typeof operand
typeof (operand)` Anyway it's just like return `("foo");` instead of `return "foo"` or `if ( (x) || (y))` they are redundant and only make things more complicated. I'm afraid it has nothing to do with minified things.

Comment: @gdoron I think you misunderstood me. You cannot remove the whitespace unless you include the parens to distinguish between the `in` operator, and the `window` object. Without the parens, removing the white space would result in `'onhashchange'inwindow` and the browser won't be able to make sense of the statement. It will raise an `unexpected identifier` message. Not the case if you wrap `window` in parens.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: That attempt to remove one character of whitespace has resulted in two extra characters. `x in n` is shorter than `x in(n)`

Comment: @JonathanSampson, if there's a minifier that removes white space between tokens ("indivisible lexical units" in the ECMA spec) , it shouldn't be used. White space in JS has syntactic meaning such that reducing white space is fine (such as turning `\r\n\t\t\t` to '` `', but eliminating it can change meaning. What would this do: `vard=document;`

Comment: @Andrew This is essentially the whole debacle that took place over automatic semicolon insertion. Users were failing to include them, which would break compressed code. I'm not suggesting minifiers would convert `'onhashchange' in (window)` to `'onhashchange'in(window)`. All I'm saying is that because of the parens, the test still works properly if - for whatever reason - you *did* remove the white space. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

`'` is a token that ends a string, so a pair of `''` are semantically unambiguous, you don't need whitespace after the end of a string for the lexer to know that it has reached the end of a string.

Another way of saying that is that this works for the same reason that `'Hello '+'world'` works.

Additionally, `in` is a keyword, not a function. It seems like you're thinking of `()` as the "function call operator", but in this case it's just a disambiguating parentheses.

It's like asking "why does `1 +(2)` work?" `+` doesn't become a function just because you follow it with a paren, and similarly the following will work:

```
function foo(){}

foo

();
```

Javascript is brittle with its whitespace rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the notation is confusing you (that maybe `in()` is a method?), but `in` is one of those elements of JS that few people correctly understand (I didn't really understand it until quite recently). This is a simplified version showing what `in` does:

```
var foo = {
    'bar':1,
    'barbar':2
}

console.log('bar' in foo); //true
console.log('baz' in foo); //false
```

What makes this all the more confusing is that you can use `in` inside a `for()` loop, as if it (`in`) were an iterator. The way I tend to think of `for` loops is like this:

```
for (exp1; condition; exp2) {
    /* statements */
}

for (condition) {
    /* statements */
}
```

In other words, the loop will continue until the `in` condition fails, which will happen when it runs out of members.